# Probability problem : enumerative combinatorics of a recruitment strategy

Tags: probability, combinatorics

$n$ candidates come to a job interview, randomly by turn. You are the recruiter and you want to recruit the best candidate, but you also want to reduce the number of interview as little as possible.

We note : $R_k\text{ : "The best candidate comes to his interview at the $k$-th one"}$ and $\mathbb{P}$ the uniform probability.

Let $m \in [\![1;n-1]\!]$ and $k\in[\![m+1,n]\!]$. The strategy is the following :

- The recruiter see the first $m$ candidates, but always eliminates them all.
- He continues and chooses the first candidate who seems to be better than the first $m$ (if he can't find a better one, he chooses the last candidate by default).

**Find the probability that the recruiter hires effectively the best candidate if this candidate comes at the $k-th$ interview.**

***What I found :***

I found that $\mathbb{P}(R_k)=\frac{1}{n}$

***My difficulties :***

I don't know how to enumerate to find this probability

Answer (score 0):

The best of the first $k-1$ candidates has to be before the watershed at $m$, otherwise the interviewer will settle for her.